# Infragistics ultrawingrid cell-level formatting

Tags: formatting, ultrawingrid

I have an Infragistics UltraWinGrid bound to a datasource which contains an amount (decimal) and a currency (string). I need to display the amount and currency formatted:

```
Data source:          Grid contents: 
Amount   Currency     Amount
12.34    EUR          EUR 12.34
22.33    USD          USD 22.33
```

I am thinking about 3 options:

1. Populate the "Amount" column in the grid with a formatted string. I don't like this option because it would mess up the sorting of decimal values.
2. Set an editor on each CELL (Cell, not Column!) in the InitializeRow event. However, I don't know which editor would be suitable - any ideas?
3. Format the Amount column (Column level!) in the InitializeLayout method somehow dependant on the Currency column (the Currency column exists in the grid as a hidden column) - but I don't know if this is possible - does anybody know how? 
   Or are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using option 2 using a `EditorWithText`.  I have 2 columns in a row - a Decimal `Value` column and string `FormatString` column.  Here's what I did to have independent formatting in the `Value` column.

```
grid.InitializeRow += (sender, e) =>
{
    DefaultEditorOwnerSettings settings = new DefaultEditorOwnerSettings();
    settings.DataType = typeof(Decimal);
    settings.Format = (string)e.Row.Cells["FormatString"].Value;
    EditorWithText editor = new EditorWithText(new DefaultEditorOwner(settings));
    e.Row.Cells["Value"].Editor = editor;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Squillman's answer is working fine.

Unfortunately, the code creates an EditorWithText instance for each row.

That's why I added this:

```
Dictionary<string, EditorWithText> dic = new Dictionary<string, EditorWithText>();

EditorWithText getEditor(string format)
{
    EditorWithText ed;
    if (!dic.TryGetValue(format, out ed))
    {
        ed = new EditorWithText(
            new DefaultEditorOwner(
                new DefaultEditorOwnerSettings { Format = format }));

        dic.Add(format, ed);
    }
    return ed;
}
```

So there is only one instance of EditorWithText by existing format.

```
grid.InitializeRow += (sender, e) =>
{
    e.Row.Cells["Value"].Editor = getEditor((string)e.Row.Cells["FormatString"].Value);
}
```